# Why does this simple CNN suddenly fail?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, mnist

I've looked at some simple CNNs from this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSDrJM6fJFM and modified the code so that it uses a MomentumOptimizer instead of AdamOptimizer, and made it so the training runs indefinitely instead of just to 1000. Around the 9500 value of i, the accuracy always goes to 0.085 and remains stuck there permanently, never changing after this. I am very confused as to what could cause this. As it progresses fine, increasing the accuracy gradually, then suddenly drops to worse than random guessing and stays there forever.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# number 1 to 10 data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

def compute_accuracy(v_xs, v_ys):
    global prediction
    y_pre = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, keep_prob: 1})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pre,1), tf.argmax(v_ys,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    result = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={xs: v_xs, ys: v_ys, keep_prob: 1})
    return result

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    # stride [1, x_movement, y_movement, 1]
    # Must have strides[0] = strides[3] = 1
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    # stride [1, x_movement, y_movement, 1]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# define placeholder for inputs to network
xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])/255.   # 28x28
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
x_image = tf.reshape(xs, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
# print(x_image.shape)  # [n_samples, 28,28,1]

## conv1 layer ##
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5, 1,32]) # patch 5x5, in size 1, out size 32
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1) # output size 28x28x32
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)                                         # output size 14x14x32

## conv2 layer ##
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5, 32, 64]) # patch 5x5, in size 32, out size 64
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2) # output size 14x14x64
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)                                         # output size 7x7x64

## fc1 layer ##
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
# [n_samples, 7, 7, 64] ->> [n_samples, 7*7*64]
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

## fc2 layer ##
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

# the error between prediction and real data
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys * tf.log(prediction),reduction_indices=[1])) # loss
train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(1e-4, 0.999).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(100000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={xs: batch_xs, ys: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(i, compute_accuracy(mnist.test.images[:1000], mnist.test.labels[:1000]))
```

This is the code I've run, I'd really appreciate any help solving this mystery thank you.

Comment: Does your previous code, with AdamOptimizer, work ? If so, what did you adapt ? This might be the beginning of the problem.

Comment: Just tried your code, and I got around 90% accuracy at 500, and up to 96% at 1000. Not sure what causes yours to fail. Ran on Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2 and tensorflow 1.8.0 . Hope this helps.

Comment: @Reverse OP specifies that the problem arises at around 9,500 iterations

Comment: He doesn't specify what was going on before that. But you're right. Do you have any clue of the latent problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I think it's the result of bad initialization values, I'll try to recode it with a smarter way to initialize all the weights and biases using orthogonal matrices. I think the gradient is exploding or something to that effect.